# Reduce screen size and manage margins

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am having an issue with responsive margins. If you look at this site as an example: https://uk.balibodyco.com/collections/suncare

If I shrink the screen size, you can see the margins reduce and then it nicely goes from 4 to 2 columsn.

With mine, it does a similar thing but the issue is the margin doesn't change before it reverts to 2 columns. So the thumbnails within each column reduces because it mainaings the 7.5% margin either side.

Does anyone know what I need to do in order to fix this to match how bali body does it?

Sample code below:

```
<div class="post_content">
        <a class="" href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/product/genji-challa-ethiopian-single-origin/">
        </a><h3><a class="" href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/product/genji-challa-ethiopian-single-origin/"></a>
        <a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/product/genji-challa-ethiopian-single-origin/">Genji Challa – Ethiopian Single Origin</a></h3> 
        
        <a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/product/genji-challa-ethiopian-single-origin/#respond"><div class="star-rating"><span style="width:0%"></span></div></a>
        <span class="tastenotes">Nectarine, blood orange, redcurrant</span>
  ...
  </div>

  <div class="post_content">
        <a class="" href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/product/genji-challa-ethiopian-single-origin/">
        </a><h3><a class="" href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/product/genji-challa-ethiopian-single-origin/"></a>
        <a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/product/genji-challa-ethiopian-single-origin/">Genji Challa – Ethiopian Single Origin</a></h3> 
        
        <a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/product/genji-challa-ethiopian-single-origin/#respond"><div class="star-rating"><span style="width:0%"></span></div></a>
        <span class="tastenotes">Nectarine, blood orange, redcurrant</span>
  ...
  </div>
  
  <div class="post_content">
        <a class="" href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/product/genji-challa-ethiopian-single-origin/">
        </a><h3><a class="" href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/product/genji-challa-ethiopian-single-origin/"></a>
        <a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/product/genji-challa-ethiopian-single-origin/">Genji Challa – Ethiopian Single Origin</a></h3> 
        
        <a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/product/genji-challa-ethiopian-single-origin/#respond"><div class="star-rating"><span style="width:0%"></span></div></a>
        <span class="tastenotes">Nectarine, blood orange, redcurrant</span>
  ...
  </div>
  
  <div class="post_content">
        <a class="" href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/product/genji-challa-ethiopian-single-origin/">
        </a><h3><a class="" href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/product/genji-challa-ethiopian-single-origin/"></a>
        <a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/product/genji-challa-ethiopian-single-origin/">Genji Challa – Ethiopian Single Origin</a></h3> 
        
        <a href="https://balancecoffee.co.uk/stage/product/genji-challa-ethiopian-single-origin/#respond"><div class="star-rating"><span style="width:0%"></span></div></a>
        <span class="tastenotes">Nectarine, blood orange, redcurrant</span>
  ...
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.woocommerce-page ul.products li.product.column-1_4 {
    width: 25%;
}

.woocommerce ul.products, .woocommerce-page ul.products {
    margin-right: -30px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.archive .slider_boxed, 
.content_wrap,
.archive .content_container{
width:85%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I suggest to make it perfectly responsive use bootstrap grid system , go through
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

In case of bali body they created a class named grid which holds 4 rows on desktop and 2 on smaller screens. you can easily do this by using bootstrap by making 4 columns on large screens (col-md-4) and 2 on smaller (col-sm-2). so if you want to change margin in smaller devices consider using a css media query for smaller screens.
you can write something like :

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px)
 .grid {
margin-left: -15px;
}
```

so this will give -15px to left. you can write as many css properties ant it will effect only on mobiles and tablet. just replace grid to your class name (i think in your case in is li.product.column-1_4).